# How can we pass multiple parameters to onSuccess method of PageMethod?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pagemethods

I'm calling PageMethod "SameMethod" from javascript method "caller" so that I can get some values from DB. After I get values, control is continuing in "onSuccess" method. Problem is that I need to use some variable values ("importantValue") from javascript method "caller" in "onSuccess" method.

```
 
function caller(){
    var importantValue = 1984;   
    PageMethod.SomeMethod(param1,..., onSuccess, onFailure)
}
```

onSuccess method should be something like this:

```
function onSuccess(pageMethodReturnValue, importantValue ){

}
```

Is it possible and, if it is, how to pass multiple parameters (besides return values of page method) to "onSuccess" method of PageMethod?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass your `importantValue` as an additional parameter when calling the PageMethod. (this is usually called the context parameter if you are searching online for more info)

```
function caller(){
    var importantValue = 1984;   
    PageMethod.SomeMethod(param1,..., onSuccess, onFailure, importantValue)
}
```

Then you can access the value in the onSuccess callback as follows:

```
function onSuccess(pageMethodReturnValue, context, methodName){
    // context == 1984
}
```

---

**Update** to explain onSuccess parameters for @JacksonLopes
There is a good description on the [aspalliance website in an article by Suresh Kumar Goudampally](http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.3)

The important bit (modified to use my parameter names) is:

> The success call back method has three parameters:
>
> - **pageMethodReturnValue** - Returns the output of the page method.
> - **context** - This is used to handle different logic when single callback is used for multiple page method requests. We can also pass
>     an array of values as the `context` parameter.
> - **methodName** - This parameter returns the name of  page method called.

Comment: could you please be more elaborate??? I mean, what is the methodName parameter in OnSuccess?????

Comment: @JacksonLopes - I've added in a bit more info.

Comment: why is it not working for me? the value of context is null for me

Answer (score 4):

You could use an anonymous function

```
PageMethod.SomeMethod(param1,..., function(){onSuccess(foo, importantValue)}, onFailure)
```